# Is the holiday season an unwise time to apply for credit?

Tags: loans, credit, economics

Given the rise in consumer spending during the holidays, do lenders mitigate the increased demand for credit by offering lower credit limits than usual, or having stricter criteria for approval?

Comment: Credit cards _want_ increased demand - it's more money for them. why would they try to limit it?

Comment: When you say "unwise" what is the risk you are trying to avoid here? That you might get denied? If so, why do you care? You either need it or you don't. It doesn't hurt anything to get denied for credit other than a short term hit on your score for the inquiry, which you get even if they accept you.

Comment: @JohnFX, to say that it "doesn't hurt anything" to take hard inquiries on your credit report isn't always true (although generally you're right).  Some credit card issuers do periodic soft pulls of their customers' credit scores, and a large enough negative shift in a score could cause them to raise the interest rate on a cardholder because they're viewed as a higher risk.  If you have "thin file" credit score (not many cards/accounts) then hard inquiries can have a much larger negative effect than people with more established histories.

Comment: @rivernet Ok. So OP's options are not apply for credit, or risk a hard credit inquiry (whether he gets the credit or not). I don't see a downside.

Comment: @johnfx, a hard inquiry is a downside to some people.  That's all I was pointing out.  Hard inquiries can have consequences for people, depending on their circumstances.  You'd be right if the person has solid credit, few recent inquiries, or has no real plan in the near term to obtain a mortgage or car loan.

Answer (score 1):

There are no advantages or disadvantages to applying for credit just because of the time of year.  The issue is more a question of the impact on *your* credit for applying, regardless of the season.

Too many inquiries in a short period of time is always a red flag for creditors, because it makes it appear as though you're shopping for credit.  Further, "hard" inquiries (meaning the creditor pulls a full copy of your bureau file) can temporarily lower your credit score, which can cause issues if you are about to refinance a house or purchase a car - the decrease in your score could affect the interest rate your lender charges.

Hard inquiries (most of the time) come from applying for credit without a pre-approval from a creditor.  Pre-approvals are sent (or offered) when creditors do a "soft" pull (meaning they get your score and some other general info that allows them to make a basic credit decision since your file indicates you meet some set of underwriting parameters they've defined).  When you're pre-approved, the creditor will tell you this, and most of the time they will never do a hard pull, although be sure to read everything thoroughly before accepting to make sure.  If they ask you to enter only the last 4 digits of your SSN, that's a sign they generally won't do a hard pull after offering a pre-approval.

To return to your original question, some retailers or other creditors may make credit *easier* to obtain during the holidays in an effort to lock in your spending with them via a store card or account.  This isn't always true.  I would strongly suggest that if you're going to apply, look for cards/retailers who offer a pre-approval with no impact to your credit score, so that you can pick and choose the right cards for you without the negative consequences of hard inquiries which could stay on your file for up to two years.

Comment: Do you think the holidays influences the amount of credit lenders are willing to extend to approved applicants?

Comment: It could, I suppose.  If retailers are struggling then it would be an incentive to offer more credit to attract shoppers or to get existing shoppers to spend more.  But keep in mind that most retailers don't manage their own cars - they pay a bank or specialty card issuer to handle all of that under the store's brand, such as Comenity, Synchrony, or Citi.  The retailers, as the client, set the parameters for card issuance and limit increase guidelines, but they generally don't get involved in the details themselves.